# Connection timed out latency

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a microservice for spring boot 2 and it interacts with other services. I got a problem that when I call another service using resttemlate, and it is not available, the main thread stops and waits for a response from this service and as a result, after 15 seconds, it receives a Connection time out response. The problem is that I cannot wait this time. I need the service to work without delay and not wait a few seconds until another service responds or does not respond. How can this problem be solved? I think you can start another thread with a request to that service, and let the main thread continue to work without delay, is this the right solution? Is there a ready-made solution in Spring Boot for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can set timeout for resttemplate. Give your desired value.

```
int timeout = 1; // time here is in milliseconds.
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory rf =
        (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    rf.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
```